# Custom SMT(Simple Message Transformation)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

There are predefined Kafka Connect SMTs, which work in chains but is there a way to write a custom SMT?

My objective is to extract a value from the column (ExtractField SMT). This field is going to be a numeric field and then in the chain I want to fetch the last digit of the extracted numeric value.

This numeric value is going to be the partition number where the message will be sent in Kafka.

I am not able to find out how to extract the last digit of the field extracted.

Comment: are you asking for help in writing the necessary Java code to extract the digit? Or to write a SMT in the first place? Can you be more clear in what your question is please.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I need help in writing the SMT to achieve this . If it is not possible with available SMT , then writing custom partitioner .

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I found a nice example https://github.com/jametson/monaka/tree/master/src/main/java/com/jametson/monaka/partitioner

Comment: A partitioner isn't an SMT...